# Issue getting CakePHP to work on MAMP in virtual host

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, mamp, virtualhost

I dont know how to get CakePHP to run in a virtual host on my local machine. I can get the code to work on the default `http://localhost:8888/caketest/` but cant get it to work from `http://cakeapp.local:8888/` where I get the warning

```
"URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server.   1) Help me configure it 2) I don't / can't use URL rewriting"
```

In MAMP's httpd.conf I added

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/me/Documents/path/to/root/root"
    ServerName cakeapp.local
</VirtualHost>
```

I saw in the help page that it expects

```
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
# Order deny,allow
# Deny from all
```

but this crashed MAMP

both are CakePHP 2.4.9 with no changes to the default download

Edit: The not working files in `/Users/me/Documents/path/to/root/root` which dont work were copied to `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs` where they then worked, so it is an issue with the virtual host

Edit 2:
I thought I had found a solution but It looks like I was wrong. I changed the virtual host to point directly to /app/webroot which has made the default page show correctly, I then proceeded to add the DebugKit plugin (which I have working in a different local host file and the rewrites for its files still dont work.

For example app/Plugin/DebugKit/webroot/css/debug_toolbar.css gets loaded on `http://localhost:8888/caketest/debug_kit/css/debug_toolbar.css` but the file in the virtual host `http://cakeapp.local:8888/debug_kit/css/debug_toolbar.css` returns a 404 error (the plugin works), the files just dont get loaded.

Comment: Check if `LoadModule mod_rewrite` is enabled in Apache's `httpd.conf`

Comment: @dbrumann it is, and it works in the localhost, but not in the virtual host (however it does work for getting to the index.php in the app/webroot so I am not sure where I can make changes to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think this works, the last time I tried to fix the directory it was not pointing at the correct directory.

I added the following to the httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "/Users/me/Documents/path/to/root/root">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you copied the code from /Application/MAMP/htdocs to /Users/me/Documents/path/to/root/root, did the .htaccess file get copied across as well? This hidden file is often left behind.

Comment: I have hidden files showing :) good point though, I'll update the question

Answer (score 0):

replace with this in your .htaccess file , it worked for me.

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteBase /path/to/cake/app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```